Why friction of a wheel is zero?
MY physics teacher told us that friction is independent of surface area. but Also said that friction in a wheel is zero because the surface of wheel is in contact with wheel for only small amount of time. How can this be explained?

It's not the time that matters, but the movement. With an (ideal) wheel, the point of contact does not move with respect to the ground, hence no friction.

This question is similar to: Friction in case of pure rolling. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

if we take the wheel to be ideal and say that it is not slipping then the velocity of the point of contact of wheel would be 0 which means there will be no relative motion between the ground and the wheel meaning that there will be no friction
but keep in mind it is only when we assume its motion to be ideal (without slipping)
